# How can I use UPDATE OR INSERT with Laravel 4?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I'm building an application in Laravel 4 and I need to run several queries as UPDATE OR INSERT queries to avoid PK violations on duplicate inserts. I haven't been able to find any way to do this with the query builder in Laravel.

Can I modify the DB class or something similar? Or will I need to just write pure SQL statements?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now we can use `User::updateOrCreate()`

Comment: Fantastic! Has been missing.

Answer (score 9):

You can use DB::statement. http://laravel.com/docs/database

```
   DB::statement('INSERT INTO comments (comments) values (?)', array('LOL'));
```

You can put ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in there.

There's unfortunately no way to do it (that I know of) with eloquent unless you do something like

```
  $user = User::find(1);

  if ($user === null) {
       $user = new User;
  }
  $user->name = 'hey'; 
  $user->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be very nice if Fluent support ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or INSERT IGNORE but it doesn't seem to. The closest solution I found was to use firstOrCreate() on your model.

```
User::firstOrCreate( array('id'=>1, 'name'=>'hey') );
```

This may do what you need without writing out the full query in some scenarios.