# SQL : INSERT if no exist and UPDATE if exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, insert

I have a program that can perform inserts and updates to the database, I get the data from API.
This is sample data when I get:

```
$uname    = $get['userName'];
$oname    = $get['offerName'];
$visitdata= $get['visits'];
$convdata = $get['conversion'];
```

I save this data to database sql. (sucess) this is a sample:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data_tester(username_data, name_offer_data, visit_data, conversion_data) VALUES('$uname','$oname', '$visitdata', '$convdata')";
```

> Sample data in database table
>
> ```
> id | username_data | name_offer_data | visit_data | conversion_data
> 1  | MOJOJO        | XXX AU          | 177        | 13
> 2  | MOJOJO        | XX US           | 23         | 4
> ```

Now, I want to save data `$uname, $oname, $visitdata, $convdata` if NOT EXIST  and UPDATE `$visitdata, $convdata` where `$uname, $oname` if EXIST

How to run the code with a simple query.
Please give me an example.
Thank you.

Comment: Then first you have to fetch data from tha data base and check that if data exist then perform update else perform insert query

You have to use insert,update and select query for it.

Comment: If this is MySQL, check out the [insert into ... on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

Comment: Read about `MySQL on duplicate key`

Comment: Tag the dbms used, the answer may depend on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called [UPSERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) and it is the part of SQL-2008 Standard. However not all DBMS-s implement it and some implement it differently.

For instance on MySQL you can use:

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

syntax ([link to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html))
or

```
REPLACE INTO
```

syntax ([link to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html)).

These methods require you to have a proper PRIMARY KEY: (username_data name_offer_data) in your case.

Some PHP frameworks support this feature too provided you are using ActiveRecord (or similar) class. In Laravel it is called [updateOrCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317193/how-can-i-use-update-or-insert-with-laravel-4) and in Yii it is called [save()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#save()-detail). So if you are using a framework try to check its documentation.

If you are using neither framework nor modern DBMS you have to implement the method yourself. Run `SELECT count(*) from data_tester WHERE username_data = ? AND name_offer_data = ?`, check if it returned any rows and call an appropriate UPDATE/INSERT sql

Comment: Yes, how to add  PRIMARY KEY in username_data and name_offer_data? 

I using ID for primary key, but don't get it by $_GET

Comment: The problem is you can't add the second Primary key (that's why it's called "Primary"). In your case unfortunately you have to simulate UPSERT in PHP by hand (issuing SELECT and then deciding on UPDATE/INSERT). The second option is to remove Primary key using `ALTER TABLE data_tester DROP PRIMARY KEY` and add a new one `ALTER TABLE data_tester ADD PRIMARY KEY (username_data, name_offer_data)` but often it is very dangerous and has too many side-effects to consider it (e.g. changing all FOREIGN KEYS)

Answer (score 0):

it's simple, try this:

```
if(isset($get['userName'])){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_transfer WHERE userName = ".$userName.";";
$result = connection()->query($sql);
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
connection()->close();
    //if is not void, means that this username exists
if ($rs != ''){
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    //InsertData

}
else{
   mysqli_free_result($result);
    //UpdateData
}
```

*chech that you have to use your PrimaryKey on where clause to ensure there are only one of this. if you use an ID and you don't get it by $_GET, you'll have to modify something to ensure non-duplicated data. For example, checking that userName cannot be duplicated or something similar

Comment: Yes, how to add PRIMARY KEY in username_data and name_offer_data? I using ID for primary key, but don't get it by $_GET

Comment: So... how do you want to check if something is duplicated if you cannot handle your primary or unique? :/

Comment: i dont know if EVERY userName can only have ONE data, or each can have N.

if my username [dondregon] can only get one data [181cm, darkhair, 21cm], simply check for userName if exists. if you dont get void, perform an update, else perform an insert, but you must stablish userName as Unique key.

Comment: Hehe.. Okay thanks before. :D
I'm new for this case, i will try searching about duplicate key.

Comment: use the code i posted before in a separated php file. you can use it as a function on you can return 1 if user exists or 0 if not. it will keep the code clean and better for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **replace into** command instead of **insert into** command.

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO data_tester(username_data, name_offer_data, visit_data, conversion_data) VALUES('$uname','$oname', '$visitdata', '$convdata')";
```

It is one of mysql good and useful feature. I used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure there is a unique key on column `username_data`, if so Mysql's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is suitable for this case, the SQL statement is like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO data_tester(username_data, name_offer_data, visit_data, 
conversion_data) VALUES('$uname','$oname', '$visitdata', '$convdata')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username_data = '$uname', name_offer_data = 
'$oname', visit_data = '$visitdata', conversion_data = '$convdata'"
```